# Best way to lookup and return data for conditions based on 2 columns and 1 row

Tags: performance, google-sheets, formula, vlookup, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets in Google Sheets. One sheet being an individual roster for an employee and another sheet containing all the errors all 99 employees have made for each individual stores. Every day we add 2 new stores worth of data in.

On the roster page, I want to be able to lookup an employees errors, based on a store name (Store names are in cell reference: D,E,F:15 in the employee roster sheet) and obviously there name (cell reference: B5), and return the 6 types of errors they have made on the day (Missed Item, Double Beep, Missed Shelf, Missed Bay, Keying Error, Total from the errors sheet)

To gain a better understanding here is my google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1awWIode75nPFbc9-d5YRUJZd0OyMWCCI8C7OKloeKjE/edit?usp=sharing

What kind of code/formula would I need? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: and you want to return what? error count or list of employee names?

Comment: @Falcon Since there are 2 new stores every day,  why you have 3 cell references in the roster page?

Comment: @player0 - Error count, So For for example, Employee1 might of had 2 missed items, 0 double beeps, 1 missed shelf, 0 missed bay, 3 keying errors, total of 20 at Store 3321)

Comment: @ZEuS Because it will show the last 3 stores they have done. (I have another section above it called Scan Rate, which already finds the last 3 stores they have done) I just haven't shown it, to not cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **D16** cell and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 {"Missed Item"; "Keying Error"; "Double Beep"; "Missed Shelf"; "Missed Bay"; "Total"}, 
 {TRANSPOSE(Errors!$B$3:$G$3), IF(
 TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Errors!"&ADDRESS(MAX(IF(Errors!$A:$A=$B$5,ROW($A:$A), )), 
 MATCH(FILTER(Errors!2:2, SEARCH(D15, Errors!2:2)), Errors!2:2, 0), 4)&
 ":"&ADDRESS(MAX(IF(Errors!$A:$A=$B$5,ROW($A:$A), )), 
 MATCH(FILTER(Errors!2:2, SEARCH(D15, Errors!2:2)), Errors!2:2, 0)+5, 4)))="", 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Errors!"&ADDRESS(MAX(IF(Errors!$A:$A=$B$5,ROW($A:$A), )), 
 MATCH(FILTER(Errors!2:2, SEARCH(D15, Errors!2:2)), Errors!2:2, 0), 4)&
 ":"&ADDRESS(MAX(IF(Errors!$A:$A=$B$5,ROW($A:$A), )), 
 MATCH(FILTER(Errors!2:2, SEARCH(D15, Errors!2:2)), Errors!2:2, 0)+5, 4))))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Im still having trouble with a lot of stores, not being able to find any data. Even after Trim, a lot of stores don't bring up data... Any ideas why?

Comment: I would need to check it. can you provide me an example? (btw I cant edit the sheet)

Answer (score 0):

paste in **D16** cell and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Errors!"&ADDRESS(4, 
 MATCH(FILTER(Errors!2:2, SEARCH(D15, Errors!2:2)), Errors!2:2, 0), 4)&
 ":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(3, 
 MATCH(FILTER(Errors!2:2, SEARCH(D15, Errors!2:2)), Errors!2:2, 0)+5, 4), 3, 105)))="", 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Errors!"&ADDRESS(4, 
 MATCH(FILTER(Errors!2:2, SEARCH(D15, Errors!2:2)), Errors!2:2, 0), 4)&
 ":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(3, 
 MATCH(FILTER(Errors!2:2, SEARCH(D15, Errors!2:2)), Errors!2:2, 0)+5, 4), 3, 105)))), 
 ROW($A4:$A105)^0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I don't think thats pulling the right data.

At 3149 Eastland Employee 1 had: 

2 Missed items, 2 Keying Errors, 0 Double Beep, 0 Missed Shelf, 0 Missed Bays and a total of 5

Im not sure where your getting the numbers 23, 4.5, 9, 10 etc from?

Comment: numbers are sums of whole columns eg. all employees

Comment: I need the numbers for just that employee (Cell reference B5), not all employees. As this is individual rosters.